# Powers of real numbers in a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Suppose we have a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p$ which converges, I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_n|^s$ converges for any $s\geq p$.

Here is my attempt,
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p <\infty \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^p = 0$. So we can find $N \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall \; n \geq N$ we have $|a_n|^p < 1$ so if $s\geq p$ then $\forall  n \geq \mathbb{N}$ we have $|a_n|^s \leq |a_n|^p$ then if I apply the comparison test I can show the sum from $N$ to $\infty$ is finite and what's left over is finite so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_n|^s < \infty$.

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: You may have to be a little bit more careful in stating your conditions. Let $a_n = n$ and $p = -2$. Then the original series is $\sum_n 1/n^2$, which converges. However, with $s = -1 \geq p$, the corresponding series diverges.

Comment: Apologies forgot to state that $s,p \geq 1$